# spawn command issue in Expect Script

Tags: linux, kali-linux, expect

I am using KALI Linux and have some trouble with an expect script.

I don't know why the spawn command doesn't perform any action, it just echos out the same text

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
spawn apt-get install expect
```

OR

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
spawn ssh 10.10.80.1
```

it just prints out the same text when I execute it using `./test.sh` , here is the result

```
spawn apt-get install expect
```

AND

```
spawn ssh 10.10.80.1
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that `expect` runs your spawn command, which starts `apt-get`, then `expect` gets to the end of the script and so it stops, and the `apt-get` is killed by a signal SIGHUP.

At the very least you should add another line

```
expect eof
```

to your script to make `expect` read from the spawned command until it gets end-of-file.

Answer (score 2):

- `send` – to send the strings to the process
- `expect` – wait for the specific string from the process
- `spawn` – to start the command

You must close every command that spawn initiates, else it will read it as a line.

Your expect script should look like this using EOF:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
spawn ssh 10.10.80.1
expect EOF
```